How can I optimize the performance of a static site while minimizing the impact of third-party scripts?
How can I optimize the performance of a static site while minimizing the impact of third-party scripts?
Problem Statement:
I need to optimize my static site’s performance according to Lighthouse/PageSpeed Insights.
I’m looking for effective methods to inject third-party scripts with minimal impact on performance.
Given the scripts I’m using (GTM with G Tag, Google Ads Remarketing, Hotjar, Poptin, Meta Pixel, and SalesIQ), what approaches or techniques have you found most effective in achieving a balance between functionality and performance? Any insights or suggestions from your experiences would be greatly appreciated!
I’ve been working hard to optimize the performance of my static website, and without any third-party scripts, the recorded performance on PageSpeed Insights is consistently above 90. However, whenever I add third-party scripts like GTM, Hotjar, Poptin, Meta Pixel, and Zoho CDN, the performance score drops significantly, often falling below 70%.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
Approach 1:
Standard Script Injection:GTM in the headMeta Pixel and Hotjar above the body tagSalesIQ and Poptin at the end of the body
Recorded Performance: 43%
Approach 2:
Caching with Service Worker:Serving files from cache
Impact on Performance: Improved, but still not optimal
Approach 3:
Cloudflare Workers & Caching:Served third-party scripts through Cloudflare Workers with a caching mechanism
Recorded Performance: Improved to 65%-80% with all third-party scripts
Cloudflare + GTM Injection:Served GTM via Cloudflare and injected other third-party scripts (Hotjar, Poptin) through the GTM container
Recorded Performance: 65%-80%
Note :

Can’t use GTM to inject hotjar, pixels or other 3rd party script in GTM container.
Tech stacks using : Html, Vanilla Javascript, Vite, Nginx, handlebars
verified and checked gtm container , no refactoring scope i found that i can reduce its size.




